# How to find in a data frame the rows that their value is True?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and in this data frame a have two columns (sometimes i have one column or more). I try to make a program that finds the rows that their values are True and also i want to make the following dictionary:
My first sublist start with number 2 because i have the first value is True and i start a new one sublist when i find a value with True again.

In this dictionary i have the key = 0 that is the table (i have one pdf table that i read it with camelot) and also the values.

[image]

```
pandas_dict = {0:[[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20],[21,18,19,29],[30,31,32,33,34]]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
pandas_dict = {'0': df.groupby(df.any(1).cumsum()).apply(
    lambda x: x.index.to_list()).iloc[1:].to_list()}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get each row that contains at least a `True`, just do:

```
df[6] | df[7]
```

Or, if you have a variable number of columns, just select the lines that contain a True value:

```
df.any(axis='columns')
```

To generate your dict:

```
pandas_dict = {"0": [
    group.index.to_list()
    for _, group in df.groupby( (df[6] | df[7]).cumsum() )
]}
```

This works by (ab)using the fact that the sum of booleans in Python is the number of `True` values. So the cumsum will generate unique values for your "groups", and you just have to take the list of indexes from each group to build your list.

Example with a randomly generated DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [random.choice([True, False]) , random.choice([True, False])]
        for i in range(34)
    ],
    columns=[6,7]
)

pandas_dict = {"0": [
    group.index.to_list()
    for _, group in df.groupby((df[6]|df[7]).cumsum())
]}
```

`pandas_dict` will contain, for my randomly generated `df`:

```
{'0': [[0],
  [1],
  [2],
  [3],
  [4],
  [5],
  [6],
  [7],
  [8],
  [9],
  [10, 11],
  [12],
  [13],
  [14],
  [15, 16],
  [17, 18, 19],
  [20],
  [21, 22],
  [23, 24, 25],
  [26],
  [27],
  [28, 29],
  [30],
  [31, 32],
  [33]]}
```